# Mac Air 2015 Stuck in Recovery / Safe mode

Tags: terminal, recovery

I sometimes let my battery die (unintentionally) and then when it is plugged in again and I switch on, I am in recovery or safe mode.
I've managed before to get back to normal mode, somehow. I don't have enough space to install Mac OS Sierra (never had before either). I can't seem to get back to normal mode, have tried everything I could find on Google. A previous time I typed a command into the terminal which may have helped, but I can't find that thread again.
Could someone please help me?!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What OS is installed? Are you saying that the internal drive is full? Safe Mode is just booting from the 'normal' OS, but with extensions turned off, so the OS on disk is working. Have you tried resetting the PRAM? (hold Option Command P R at boot). Try not to let your Mac's battery run down, particularly if it's 8 years old.